# Need help printing the first N numbers in the hofstadter female sequence in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I'm new here so I apologize in advance if my post is poor.
I'm trying to build a list that contains the first n numbers of the following mutually recursive hofstadter sequence:

```
F(0) = 1
M(0) = 0
F(n) = n - M(F(n-1)), n > 0
M(n) = n - F(M(n-1)), n > 0
```

I'm trying to do this in OCaml, which is a new language for me. After struggling all day on this problem I came up with this:

```
open Printf

let list = [];;
let rec female (n: int) = 
    if n == 0 then 1::list
    else let x = n - male(female(n-1)) in x::list
and male (n:int) =
    if n == 0 then 0::list
    else let x = n - female(male(n-1)) in x::list
in female 4;; (** test number*)

let () = List.iter (printf "%d ") list
```

but it keeps producing a type error on line 8 that reads

> This pattern matches values of type int
> but a pattern was expected which matches values of type int list

Can someone help me understand why I'm getting this error? Functional programming isn't really my strong suit.

Comment: You may find your code more expressive (and thus easier to reason out) taking advantage of OCaml's pattern matching syntax.  `let rec female n = match n with 0 -> ... | _ -> ...` vs. using if/else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out, thanks to jeff in the comments. Here's my solution:

```
let rec female (n: int) = 
    match n with
        | 0 -> 1
        | _ -> n - male(female(n-1))
and male (n:int) =
    match n with
        | 0 -> 0
        | _ -> n - female(male(n-1));;
        
let rec l i =
  if i < 10 then female i :: l (i+1) 
  else [] 
  in
List.iter (fun item -> print_int item; print_newline ()) (l 0)
```

prints the first 10 numbers in the hofstadter female sequence: 6 5 5 4 3 3 2 2 1 1

Answer (score 0):

You have this subexpression:

```
male (female (n-1))
```

From this we can conclude that the parameter of `male` is the same type as the result of `female`. But just above we see that `female` returns this in one case:

```
1 :: list
```

This is a list of ints.

So we know that the first parameter of `male` should be a list of ints. However, when you actually define `male` you have this:

```
and male (n:int) =
```

The compiler is telling you that you have two conflicting requirements for the first parameter of `male`. In one place it's a list of ints and in another place (the definition of `male` itself) you say it's an int.

You need to have a consistent plan for what the parameters to `male` and `female` should be.

Comment: Thank you! So it looks like I have a design flaw, how could I go about fixing this?

Comment: What is `male n` supposed to return? Is it supposed to return the *n*th number in the `M` sequence as you have defined it? If so, you don't need to deal with lists at all. You can just deal with numbers. Or is it supposed to return the list of the first `n` numbers of the `M` sequence? That's a little harder (it involves more FP tactics).

Comment: That was the right question to ask. so say both male and female return the nth element of sequence, would it be logically correct have a separate loop calling for each 0 - n elements and building the list that way?